# Unity2d how to make a object follow another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been having a ton of struggle on this, I have been trying to make my enemy follow the player whenever the player was in a certain range. I tried using a 2dcollider  set to trigger but that did not give any results.

This is my detection script that is on the gameobject that has a trigger 2d box collider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rigidbody2D newtargetrb;
    public Transform newtarget;
    public bool FoundTarget;
    public Collider2D thiscollider;
    // Use this for initialization
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            newtarget = other.GetComponent<Transform>();
            newtargetrb = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            FoundTarget = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the script that I am using for the enemy that should follow the player after using the child object with the script above detecting the player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieStudent : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public Transform  target;
    public Rigidbody2D Rb;
    public Rigidbody2D targetrb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        var myhealth = GetComponent<BaseEnemyScript>().Health;
        var mydamage = GetComponent<BaseEnemyScript>().Damage;
        var mytarget = GetComponentInChildren<DetectPlayerScript>().newtarget;
        var TargetFound = GetComponentInChildren<DetectPlayerScript>().FoundTarget;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        target = GetComponentInChildren<DetectPlayerScript>().newtarget;
        var myspeed = GetComponent<BaseEnemyScript>().Speed;
        targetrb = GetComponentInChildren<DetectPlayerScript>().newtargetrb;
        if (GetComponentInChildren<DetectPlayerScript>().FoundTarget == true)
        {
            Vector2 TargetDIR = target.transform.position;
            Rb.AddForce(TargetDIR * myspeed);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the Rigidbody 2d is the cause of this or not, but here is a screen shot of the scene if this helps.

[The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlSJi.png)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)` function? First debug and see if the breakpoints are getting hit inside the function. Then post the updated info. You can also test it using `Debug.Log()` to see if trigger enter is happening

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is when I noticed that I did not put in the Player Tag on my Player GameObject. I am a duffas.

Comment: It happens. All of us makes mistake. Glad it helped you out :) You can write your own answer and mark it as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer was just putting the tag Player on my Player Game Object.